# Emgu cvEigenVV different result from matlab eigs

Tags: c#, matlab

I'm trying to calculate eigen vectors and values of a matrix by Emgu CV, cvEigenVV method. But the result of the calculated eigen vectors are different from what I have obtained by matlab eigs function before...the magnitude of the numbers are same but their signs are different!!! any ideas why is that? ad what I should do?!
here's the code I've written in Emgu CV:

```
epsilon = 0.0;
image_eigen_vectors = new Matrix<double>(image_covariance.Rows, image_covariance.Cols);
image_eigen_values = new Matrix<double>(image_covariance.Rows, 1);
CvInvoke.cvEigenVV(image_covariance, image_eigen_vectors, image_eigen_values, epsilon, 0, 0);
```

and here's the code I've used in matlab:

```
[eigen_vectors eigen_value]=eigs(covariance_convert, 87);
```

help please! thanks in advance!